# Azure Functions .Net 5: Is it possible to implement POCO binding somehow?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-5, c#-9.0

When moving my functions to .net5 I faced the fact that POCO binding that worked fine with 3.1 is not applicable with .net 5 anymore for some reason. They say it will be implemented at some point maybe, but for the certain reasons I need it now. Tried to find some hacky way to implement this, but failed. The best thought I had was to implement explicit operator in my DTO object which will cast HttpRequestData to it's type, but the problem is that HttpRequestData is an abstract type, and it's concrete implementation type is internal. After that I tried to cast the input parameter to HttpRequestData in middleware with reflection, but parameters are stored in IReadOnlyDictionary which is immutable. So I ran out of ideas now. Maybe someone found workaround to this and can kindly share, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some minimal code where you are trying to do this and failing ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using the "dotnet-isolated" mode (only way to run on .NET 5).
I'm trying to find a more elegant solution to this as well.

Meanwhile, what I did was to deserialize the data myself, inside the function.

```
var body = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
var myobject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyPocoClass>(json);
```

I would really prefer if the runtime did it by itself, but I couln't find a way yet. I read somewhere that it is possible to create our own binding code, but I haven't tried it.

I noticed that I could bind to individual properties of the json payload, but not to an object...

I hope this arrives in Azure Functions v4 + .NET6, since it is right around the corner.

Comment: Right, I'm doing the same thing, but it's ugly, and I had to change all functions signatures because of that. My idea was to create some underlying hack not to change functions definitions, so when this functionality will be available, I just remove it, but didn't find the way to implement this